# Is Cookie middleware required to glue OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, owin, openid-connect

Our application consists of:

- Front-end, which is a SPA using OAuth2 to authenticate on our back-end
- Back-end, which is a ASP.NET OWIN application acting as a OAuth2 server and OpenID connect client
- 3rd party OpenID connect provider

So, when a unauthenticated user browses to the SPA, the SPA starts an OAuth2 implicit flow with our back-end, which causes a redirect to the OpenID connect provider that displays the login form. Once the user logs in, a JWT token is posted to the OIDC callback endpoint on our back-end which triggers the cookie middleware that stores the identity in a cookie AND redirects to the OAuth2 authorize endpoint which resumes the implicit flow by returning an access token in the URL fragment.

To do this, I currently use the OWIN Cookie middleware to glue the OpenID Connect middleware with the OAuth2 middleware, where the cookie expiration is very short as the only purpose is to pass an identity from the OpenID connect callback to the OAuth2 authorize endpoint. Therefore I wanted to ask if there's a way to do the same but without the cookie middleware as it feels a little bit redundant in this setup.

For what it's worth, this is our middleware configuration:

```
// Clear default inbound claim mappings, otherwise the 'sub' claim is mapped to a ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier which is not what we want
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AllowedAudiences = new[] { options.JwtOptions.Audience },
    IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new[] { new X509CertificateSecurityKeyProvider(options.JwtOptions.Issuer, options.JwtOptions.SigningCertificate) }
});

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    CookieName = "Brownie",
    CookieHttpOnly = true,
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    SlidingExpiration = false
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AuthenticationType = Constants.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationType,
    MetadataAddress = options.OpenIdConnectOptions.MetadataAddress,
    ClientId = options.OpenIdConnectOptions.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = options.OpenIdConnectOptions.ClientSecret,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectNotificationHandlers(options),
    RedirectUri = new Uri(options.ApplicationUrl, options.OpenIdConnectOptions.CallbackPath.ToString()).ToString(),
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = "openid profile offline_access",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
});

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AuthenticationType = Constants.OAuth2AuthenticationType,
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = options.AuthorizeEndpoint,
    TokenEndpointPath = options.TokenEndpoint,
    AllowInsecureHttp = false,
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = options.JwtOptions.TokenLifetime,
    AccessTokenFormat = new JwtTokenFormat(options.JwtOptions),
    Provider = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerProvider(context => context.GetAutofacLifetimeScope().Resolve<IClientRepository>())
});
```

Passing `Constants.OAuth2AuthenticationType` to `SignInAsAuthenticationType` of the OpenID Connect middleware doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? My scenario is a little different but similar enough; I'm configuring and using cookie auth separately to the OAuth/OpenID config and don't want them to clash (AddAuthorization().AddCookie etc)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is that best practice and to use the "state" parameter be used as stated in the [OpenID Connect Basic Client Implementer's Guide 1.0 - draft 37 Section 2.1.1.1.  Request Parameters](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#RequestParameters)

"RECOMMENDED. Opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback. Typically, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF, XSRF) mitigation is done by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie."

Comment: This is already taken care of by the openidconnect middleware itself and is another cookie than the one I talk about in my question. Anyway thanks for chiming in.